# How to remove view lines in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word I have some lines that show me every line, it doesn't matter it's a blank line by pressing enter or a line with text. I don't know what are them and I don't even know how to call them so I can't google how to remove them.

Here is how my Word looks
[image: looks]

This is not a table, this is View of every Word document while editing it.
When I press to print page it looks as normal

Here is how page look after pressing Print or CTRL+P
[image: Here is how page look after pressing Print or CTRL+P]
So when I send it to Print or on a printed page it looks as normal. This is just some type a View mode when editing documents.

Comment: I tried to load another Windows profile and there all it's okay. Then I copied files from _C:\Users\NewProfile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates_


To


_C:\Users\OldProfile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates_ and it didn't help! I still have this lines

Answer (score 0):

### This is "Text Boundaries"

You want the option to show them unchecked.
`File > Options > Advanced`

[image: Advanced Options dialog - text Boundaries]

Until Word 2013, these were useful.

Here is a link to [my page on this](https://addbalance.com/word/textBoundaries.htm#PageStart) for more background.

**Bonus tip:**
You should not have empty paragraphs. Each of those boxes designates a place where you pressed Enter and started a new paragraph.

See [Basic Concepts in Microsoft Word](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/concepts/rules_enterparagraphs.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly, especially [Why you should press Enter only once at the end of a paragraph](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/concepts/rules_enterparagraphs.html).